# No partition found

Tags: linux, windows-8

I had windows 8.1 and Linux on my system . Somehow it got corrupt and shows no partition found I then reinstalled Ubuntu with the option 
Delete all files, photos from operating system.  It seems like it deleted all my D and E drive data, is there any way that I can recover that data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Version:** Possible some of the files can be recovered, but it depends on how much time/money it is worth to you.

If the D:\ and E:\ drives where partitions on the main disk, the Ubuntu Install would have removed it.

File Recovery depends on how much you have used your system since you installed it. The longer you use it, the less likely it is to recover files.

If these are important files, Shutdown the computer and remove the hard drive now, not in five minutes, or when updates are done. NOW. I would recommend removing power over a typical shutdown. This has a chance to corrupt your Ubuntu system, but it's new, it won't take to long to reinstall it.

After you do that, you have a limited amount of options. You could find a professional to recover the data for you, however this can be expensive.

Other than having a professional do it, there is very little you can do. You might be able to restore your old partition scheme using the Linux `testdisk` command. If you do this, make sure to use a live USB or another system, and do not boot from the Ubuntu installed on the HDD.